# Python Altair, query for current axis limits

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I know how to set axis limits and whatnot, but how do I query for currently used axis limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible unless you specifically set an axis limit first:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars.url

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
)

chart.to_dict()
```

```
{'config': {'view': {'continuousWidth': 400, 'continuousHeight': 300}},
 'data': {'url': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-datasets@v1.29.0/data/cars.json'},
 'mark': 'circle',
 'encoding': {'x': {'field': 'Horsepower', 'type': 'quantitative'},
  'y': {'field': 'Miles_per_Gallon', 'type': 'quantitative'}},
 '$schema': 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.2.0.json'}
```

If you set the domain, you can see it in the spec:

```py
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Horsepower:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 250])),
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
)

chart.to_dict()
```

```
{'config': {'view': {'continuousWidth': 400, 'continuousHeight': 300}},
 'data': {'url': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-datasets@v1.29.0/data/cars.json'},
 'mark': 'circle',
 'encoding': {'x': {'field': 'Horsepower',
   'scale': {'domain': [0, 250]},
   'type': 'quantitative'},
  'y': {'field': 'Miles_per_Gallon', 'type': 'quantitative'}},
 '$schema': 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.2.0.json'}
```

and get it via `chart.to_dict()['encoding']['x']['scale']['domain']`.

Comment: Hmm the reason I want to do this is specifically that I can't set it ahead of time, and need to know what Altair has automatically decided it's going to be. Thanks anyway, at least now I know I can't. Strange that I can't though.

Comment: @Ray The reason you can't get it is because it happens via VegaLite's defaults on the JS side. You would probably be able to write JS to get it, but since that is a bit unfeasible, you could also rely on the default rules in VegaLite. The domainMin will be 0 for continuous scales (unless they are binned I think). The domainMax will be the max value in your data + some padding to get to a nice round number. If you need to know exactly you can set `alt.Scale(nice=False)` which makes it the exact value of the max in your data.  https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#continuous-scales

Comment: You've personally answered so many of my Altair questions I can't thank you enough @joelostblom.

Comment: Happy to help @Ray =)